# How to extract source ip and host address from a pcap file into a .csv file? Any ideas on a way to do it?

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump, tshark

```
tshark -r example.pcap -Y http.request -T fields -e http.host -e ip.dst -e http.request.full_uri
```

I tried using this command however it just gives me `source ip`. I need to make sure i get `source ip` and `destination ip` so i can list out the websites visited by a particular source from a pcap file. Any suggestions on a better method or improvement on this command?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Python, use Scapy's Python bindings.

With Scapy installed, you can use the `rdpcap()` function to grab all of the packets, which will be given to you as a list, which you can then iterate over.  As you iterate over the list, you can extract any fields out of any of the layers and print them any way that you'd like!

Answer (score 0):

You state that *"it just gives me `source ip`. I need to make sure i get `source ip` and `destination ip`"*; however, it looks to me like you're getting the destination ip, judging by `-e ip.dst` in your command:

```
tshark -r example.pcap -Y http.request -T fields -e http.host -e ip.dst -e http.request.full_uri
```

... so why not just include `-e ip.src` so you get both source and destination IP addresses?

I don't know, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for.